# Interference problems in program

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi for my java revision I'm going through past paper questions and I'm stuck. I'm given this code:

```
class FriendFinderThread extends Thread {
    // number of FriendBook friends
    int numFriends = 0;
    public void run() {
        // join, then leave FriendBook
        FriendBook.join(this);
        try { Thread.sleep(10000); }
        catch (InterruptedException(ie) {}
        FriendBook.leave(this);
    }
}

class FriendBook {
    // list of FriendBook members
    static Vector<FriendFinderThread> members =
    new Vector<FriendFinderThread>();
    static void join(FriendFinderThread f) {
        // add a new friend to all existing members
        int size = members.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            members.elementAt(i).numFriends++;
        }
        f.numFriends = size; // new member’s friends
        members.add(f); // add to list of members
    }
    static void leave(FriendFinderThread f) {
        members.remove(f); // remove from list
        int size = members.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            members.elementAt(i).numFriends--;
        }
    }
    public static void main() {
        for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
            new FriendFinderThread().start();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having real trouble understanding what is going on, could someone please explain what is happening in the code and how the code could have problems with interference.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At some point one thread will call join. This uses members.size() and accesses each element in members. While doing so another member will leave (the later threads will be slower as they loop over more elements, so at some point there will be more leaving than joining). This means that members.elementAt(members.size()-1) will throw an error.